# How to handle subdomains in NancyFX routes

Tags: nancy

Really liking the simplicity and the power of the NancyFX framework, but I ran into something which I cannot find a good solution for; how to route based on subdomains?

For example; I want to define a route that matches something like

`{account}.website.com/restofroute`

While having other parts of my site react to the normal www.website.com routing. So basically I want multi tenant support in my site based on the host name.

I found some ways to create and hookup a **TrieNode** so I can match the host header against some pattern and extract the account itself, but I don't see how I can link this up with the routes itself. Somehow I need to do this in the rootnode I think, so I override the **GetMatches** and add my local captures to it. Local captures are generated by some regex and contain something like *{'account', 'www'}*.

I thought I could create something like:

```
Get["/", a=>a.IsWwwRoute()] = parameters =>
```

Where IsWwwRoute is a method extension looking at the parameters collection for the account parameter that I included using the local captures. If set to 'www' let it pass, otherwise we use another route (which then uses the account parameter). But I cant find the value anywhere (parameters is null).

So what is the best way to add subdomain routing to NancyFX?

Comment: What is it you want to do with the account information? Do you really want all of your routes to start with {account}.website.com ? I would suggest a Before-hook in your application, and possibly URL-rewriting based on that. Quite an easy way to create multi-tenant. However, it depends on what you need the {account} info for, so I need a bit more context before I can give u a definitive answer :-)

Comment: If you are hosting on IIS you could do URL rewriting with AAR to turn {account}.website.com/myroute into www.website.com/{account}/myroute. In your Nancy application code math the rewritten URL. Client side code cannot see the rewrite so they haven't a clue, yet your service side code can act as though only receiving requests on one host. You do have to be careful when rendering URLs back to the client though - they need to be in the {account}.website.com form.

Comment: What I want is a public site with some information, an admin backend so the customer can setup his service and a tenant website (tenantname.website.com). This last site display and interact with customers of the tenant.

That first part is no problem; public site and admin module is al working nicely with nancy as they use relative paths, but I only want them to be available with the www address.

The tenant part is basically a different site hosted by the same server and the name of the tenant need to be known to the application to lookup the right data to show.

Comment: Correction: That is ARR not AAR. Info on ARR can be found at http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing. FWIW it sounds to me like that would solve your problem. Alternatively you couldof course just have several separate Nancy application: (1) The public site, (2) the admin site and (3) the tenant site. The tenant site could run in many instances while using the same DB if needed.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I dont want to redirect. Basically I want control over not only the relative part of the url, but the full url. Similar to here: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/aspnet-mvc-domain-routing.aspx

Comment: And I can detect the account name given a regex inside a RootNode (TrieNode). But I dont know how to pass that account and restrict certain routes to only apply at www and other at the tenant part. So how to make absolute routes instead of relative routes is basically the question.