# How to set up custom routing for wildcard subdomains in Nancyfx

Tags: c#, routes, nancy

This question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516972/how-to-handle-subdomains-in-nancyfx-routes), but I am not sure enough detail was given to provide an answer.

I would like to implement custom routing that allows me to be able to match a route segment depending on the subdomain of the URL.

For example, I would like to be able to do something similar to this:

```
// This route should match where the URL is 
//    www.mysite.com
Get["/"] = _ => return "Home";

// This route should match where the URL is 
//    {anything else}.mysite.com
Get["/:subdomain"] = _ => return "Subdomain home";
```

I would like the `:subdomain` route to be a 'catch-all' for any requests that come in with a URL that is not `www.mysite.com`. I can than check which 'virtual subdomain' is being accessed and display content accordingly.

This is to allow users to create their own account and receive their own subdomain, for example `joebloggs.mysite.com`.

I understand that custom routing is achieved by inheriting from `TrieNode` as per Phill Haydon's post [here](http://www.philliphaydon.com/2013/04/nancyfx-implementing-your-own-routing/). Is there a way that I can access the full URL from inside the `Match` method here? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think you could do that using route conditionals: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Defining-routes#condition
In the route conditions you have access to the NancyContext which gives you access to the request URL.